# Can I avoid the aggregate when using a group by?

Tags: sql

I am looking to join one column from one table to another. However, the only common columns are the timestamp and ID; these contain multiple of the same date/time or ID as there are multiple ID's per 10 minute period. I understand this creates an issue with joining the tables due to a many to many relationship. I can get the data to work with the code below aside from the tg.value2 column as it won't work without the aggregate due to the group by. But I need the group by to prevent the multiplying of rows.

Only work around I can see is to add the aggregate to tg.value2, however I don't want this. I need the data in that column to simply appear as it is without any aggregates, joining to the TimeStamp and ID from tbl1 and producing the corresponding value.

```
    SELECT
       t.TimeStamp,
       t.ID,
       AVG(t.value1) AS AvgVal1,
       AVG(tg.value2) AS AvgVal2
    FROM [dbo].[tbl1] as t
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl2] AS tg ON t.TimeStamp = tg.TimeStamp
    GROUP BY t.TimeStamp, t.ID
    ORDER BY t.TimeStamp desc, t.ID
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Gordon: Image below shows the 2 tables and the desired output.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JY0bh.png

Thank you

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: Hi Gordon, added a link showing the tables in an image, it won't let me embed at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to `join` on both `timestamp` and `id`:

```
SELECT t.TimeStamp, t.ID, t.value1, tg.value2
FROM [dbo].[tbl1] t JOIN
     [dbo].[tbl2] tg
      ON t.TimeStamp = tg.TimeStamp AND t.ID = tg.ID
ORDER BY t.TimeStamp desc, t.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT
   t.TimeStamp,
   t.ID,
   t.value1 AS AvgVal1,
   tg.value2 AS AvgVal2
FROM [dbo].[tbl1] as t
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl2] AS tg ON t.TimeStamp = tg.TimeStamp
GROUP BY t.TimeStamp, t.ID, t.value1, tg.value2
ORDER BY t.TimeStamp desc, t.ID
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but this has returned a duplication of my rows. e.g. mutiple of the same timestamp and ID, where there should only be x amount of unique ID's per 10 minute period

Comment: You need to use aggregate and sub queries. Aggregate both tables and then join